# ExpandListview Problem in android

Tags: android, xml

```
public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {



    private Context myContext;
      public ExpAdapter(Context context) {
       myContext = context;
      }
      public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return 0;
      }

      public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainscreenadvandprochlidrow, null);
       }
```

i have used a custom expandable list view with BaseExpandableListAdapter

added an edit text to the group and there are child nodes for it...now when i click on group indicator..it doesn't expand with its child nodes...if i remove edit ext from group it expands...now i made edit text focus able part false...list view expands until i click on edit text...what is the preferred solution??

Comment: I think this will really help you http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/50f0fc185da8fe4d?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

in your activity:
   expandlist.setPressed(false); (expandlist is your  custom expandable list view )
ExpAdapter expAdapter  = new ExpAdapter(context);
expAdapter.ExpandableListView(expandlist);

in the ExpAdapter,add like this:

```
public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
```

private ExpandableListView expandlist;
      private ExpandableListView expandlist;

```
  public void setExpandableListView(ExpandableListView expandlist){
  this.expandlist = expandlist;
  }


@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,       View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isExpanded){
                expandlist.collapseGroup(groupPosition)
            }else{
                expandlist.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            }
        }
    });
```

return convertView;
}